# Windows local user descriptiion

Tags: local

How can I update local users description on Windows servers with a script.
Can you provide some examples that I reference with VB script or Powershell. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far and what errors, if any, you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Got the below script which is doing the job for me :)

```
   Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/test")
   objUser.FullName = "Test User Account"
   objUser.Description = "This account should used for test purposes only."
   objUser.SetInfo
```